# Can grape juice be used for kiddush levana?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I understand that ideally red wine should generally be used for *kiddush*. On *Pesach*, I have heard that one should go to great lengths to drink wine (rather than grape juice) for the four cups at the *seder*. On the other hand, many families use grape juice *lechatchila* for regular *shabbos kiddush* throughout the year.

Of course, for *kiddush **levana*** we obviously prefer white wine. But what about grape juice? Is it permitted to use white grape juice for *kiddush levana*? Could we possibly even be *yotzei* with red grape juice?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I have to find a source as to if you may use grape juice at all.

However, if you could, red grape juice would be prohibited. Red grape juice would correspond to a red moon. This commonly occurs just prior and immediately after a total eclipse, meaning that the moon is barely visible. That is not a time to say Kiddush Levana, because an eclipse occurs at full moon, and Kiddush levana must be said BEFORE full moon.